# How to make Google Analytics count pop up posts

Tags: post, popup, google-analytics

I have a wordpress site where you can view posts in two ways. You can view them on their single page or you can click on thumbs from the homepage and view them in an ajax popup that shows the full post. My problem obviously is that Analytics isn't counting the popup views. I use a template to popup the post and I'm looking for a way to make analytics recoginze it as a page view and tell me what post it was. I tried adding the analytics code to the top of the template page but that didn't do anything. Any ideas? I use the SimpleModal jquery plugin to popup posts and call them like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('a.postpopup').live('click', function(){
            var id = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    jQuery('<div id="ajax-popup"></div>').hide().appendTo('body').load('http://mysite.com/ajax-handler/?id='+id).modal({
               opacity:90,
               position: ["0%"],
               containerCss:{width:"100%"},
               overlayClose:true,
               onOpen: function (dialog) {
             dialog.overlay.fadeIn('200', function () {
          dialog.data.hide();
           dialog.container.fadeIn('500', function () {
        dialog.data.fadeIn('slow');
           });
             });
               },
               onClose: function (dialog) {
             dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
          dialog.container.hide('500', function () {
        dialog.overlay.fadeOut('200', function () {
            $.modal.close();
        });
          });
            });
              }
            });
            return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simulate a page view by using [_trackPageView](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1006243)

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics has several options to track non-pageview related user activity that I think you could use here:

1. **Virtual pageviews** - as mentioned by user273895, you can add the call to your code when the dialog pops-up to see a "fake" pageview in your reports with a title like '/popup/post-name'
2. **Events** - you can instrument the above call with an event, for example: _trackEvent("popup", "click", "post-name"). The interaction is then trackable in the event reports and can be used to specify additional segments and filters for more advanced analysis.
3. **Custom variables** - you can set up a page or session level custom variable to record the interaction.

I'd suggest the first 2 options. Personally I tend to use events for this sort of thing but in your case it may make more sense to use a virtual pageview.

Comment: So I need to place a separate script for the analytics code on the template that contains the popup post?

Comment: Right, but not a separate script - rather you'll need to instrument the specific action you want to track by calling a function from the analytics tracking script that you already include in your WordPress site. So, in your popup code, identify where the dialog is opened and then add a call to either _trackPageview or _trackEvent. For example, if you use the async tracking code, you could try: _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/popup/post-name']);